# Spring MVC, Form and Dependency Injection

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Currently learning Spring MVC with Spring 3, I'm trying to find the correct way to receive a form and handle it. That is what I've got at the moment :

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUserInfoIntoSession(Personne personne,
        HttpSession session, ModelMap model) {
    //

    session.setAttribute("personne", personne);
    return "ageAndAddress";
}
```

1. Is this the correct way to handle a SimpleForm ? As the SimpleFormController has been deprecated ...
2. What if, Personne was not a class but an Interface, and I would like to, say, have an xml configuration find to decide which implementation I want to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simplify it to something like this...

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("personne")
public class MyController {
    ....
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveUserInfoIntoSession(@ModelAttribute Personne personne, ModelMap model) {
        return "ageAndAddress";
    }
```

However, I would suggest you avoid passing form state via HTTP sessions. Request parameters + model is usually sufficient for most cases. If you have a complex wizard-like form, try better Spring WebFlow.

Comment: Actually I was trying to replicate the AbstractWizardFormController behavior